# Handle Java Socket connection between 2 JFrames

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create a client/server application using sockets, I have 2 JFrames (2 seperate classes) , a user will initially open up the one frame and there's a button to go to the other JFrame, when clicked it disposes the previous frame and opens the new frame.

I'd like to know how I could switch back and forth between these 2 JFrames without my program crashing and needing to forcefully close, I am establishing the connection in the constructor of each JFrame.

```
try {
    server = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
     
    // creates & instantiates objectInput and output streams
    getStreams();
} catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("error creating socket: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

I have these in the constructor of both JFrames

---

EDIT

**Server**

```
public class Testserver {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket client;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

    public Testserver() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("error creating server socket: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void listenForClient() {

        try {
            System.out.println("Server is running and is waiting/listening for a connection to be established.");
            ////JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server is running and is waiting/listening for a connection to be established." );
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("A client has connected");

            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            processClient();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    
    
    private void processClient() {

        do {
            try {
                String messageFromClient = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                
                // check for clients requests and handle them (database etc)
                System.out.println("[CLIENT] " + messageFromClient);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Testserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                break;
            }

        } while (true);
        
        closeConnections();

    }
    
    
    private void closeConnections() {
        try {
            objectInputStream.close();
            objectInputStream.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testserver().listenForClient();
    }
}
```

---

**CustomerGUI**

```
public class CustomerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private Socket server;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton btnAdminGUI;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    
    public CustomerGUI() {
        
        btnAdminGUI = new JButton("Go to Admin GUI");
               
        try {
            server = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
            
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            
            objectOutputStream.writeObject("from Customer");
            objectOutputStream.flush();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage()););
        }
        
        btnAdminGUI.addActionListener(this);

    }
    
    
    public void setGUI() {
        
        
        add(btnAdminGUI);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CustomerGUI().setGUI();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource() == btnAdminGUI) {
           new AdminGUI().setGUI();
           dispose();
       }
    }
}
```

---

**AdminGUI**

```
public class AdminGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private Socket server;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton btnCustomerGUI;
    private final int PORT = 5432;
    
    public AdminGUI() {
        
        btnCustomerGUI = new JButton("Go to Customer GUI");
               
        try {
            server = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
            
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            
            objectOutputStream.writeObject("from Admin");
            objectOutputStream.flush();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        btnCustomerGUI.addActionListener(this);

    }
    
    
    public void setGUI() {
        
        
        add(btnCustomerGUI);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource() == btnCustomerGUI) {
           new CustomerGUI().setGUI();
           dispose();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're blocking the EDT call your `getStreams()` method from an executor serviceive. `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(this::getStreams);` or if you want an answer, include a complete compilable example.

Comment: I think so yeah, my program hangs and when I force close it only, then the next JFrame opens up and I immediately get this error, then it closes the second frame

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

As for the code, I don't know how to send a compilable example because it's going to be pretty long and I don't know if anyone would want to look through all the boilerplate stuff with Swing etc

Comment: One `JFrame` per app! Why do you have two?

Comment: It doesn't have to be that long, even with all the boiler plate of swing. One JFrame and a button, plus an ActionListener.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post a solution this because I have done something similar recently, but I don't have a UI for it yet.

The idea is MVC, with two models, a Server and Client and there are two Views, JPanels, which can be displayed in a window/jframe/dialog, whichever is appropriate. The Controller is essentially an api for interacting with the model, for this simple example the controllers will be mixed with the models. I think this example has a lot of flaws, but I think it gives a good idea of what needs to be done.

A button starts a course of action,

```
serverControls.addActionListener( evt ->{ } );
```

The button does one of two actions, either it starts the server or it stops the server.

```
serverLoop.submit( ()->{
    server.listen();
    //should notify a listener that the server has stopped.
});
```

`serverLoop` is another thread of execution, `server.listen()` is a long running task. It shouldn't return until we want the server to stop listening.

The other button is on the client. It has a similar structure..

```
 clientControls.addActionListener( evt->{
            clientLoop.submit( () -> client.connect( server ) );
            clientLoop.submit( 
                () -> SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
                    () -> response.setText( client.communicate() )
                ) 
            );
        });
```

First the client is going to connect, then it communicates.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ClientServerApp{
    
    static class Server{
        volatile boolean available = false;
        public void listen(){
            try{
                available = true;
                synchronized( this ){
                    wait(5000);
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                //if the server terminates unexpectedly.
            }finally{
                available = false;
            }
        }
        public void stopListening(){
            
        }
    }
    
    static class Client{
        Server connected;
        public void connect(Server host){
            connected = host;
        }
        
        public String communicate(){
            
            if(connected != null){
                if(connected.available){
                    return "connected";
                } else{
                    return "cannot connect";
                }
            }
            return "no host";
        }            
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Server server = new Server();
            Client client = new Client();
            
            ExecutorService serverLoop = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            JPanel serverView = new JPanel();
            JButton serverControls = new JButton("start");
            serverView.add( serverControls );
            
            serverControls.addActionListener( evt ->{
                if(serverControls.getText().equals("start") ){
                    serverControls.setText("stop");
                    serverLoop.submit( ()->{
                        server.listen();
                        //should notify a listener that the server has stopped.
                    });
                } else{
                    server.stopListening();
                    serverLoop.submit( ()->{
                        //will be run after the listen loop has completed. 
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () - >
                            serverControls.setText("start") 
                        );
                    });
                }
            } );
            
            JPanel clientView = new JPanel();
            JButton clientControls = new JButton("connect");
            JTextField response = new JTextField(40);
            clientView.add( clientControls );
            clientView.add(response);
            
            ExecutorService clientLoop = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            System.out.println("creating client action listener");
            clientControls.addActionListener( evt->{
                clientLoop.submit( () -> client.connect( server ) );
                clientLoop.submit( () -> 
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
                        () -> response.setText( client.communicate() ) 
                    ) 
                );
            });
            
            JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
            mainWindow.setContentPane( serverView);
            mainWindow.pack();
            mainWindow.setVisible(true);
            
            JDialog clientWindow = new JDialog( mainWindow, "Client Window");
            clientWindow.setContentPane(clientView);
            clientWindow.pack();
            clientWindow.setVisible(true);
            
    }
    
}
```

In a more complete example, you would probably have a Listener interface, so that your swing gui can response to changes in state of the server or the client, and a controller that manages the threads.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post with my code for the server and 2 java classes for connecting to it, the server is supposed to be running immediately once it's launched and start listening to clients requests, when the opens the CustomerGUI and clicks the button, that's where the gui hangs instead of going to the AdminGUI.

Comment: Okay I think i've got it working now.. I've created a seperate class implementing Runnable which handles the clients requests in a while loop within the run method.

In my test server class I create and instantiate the Server Socket and have a while loop that accepts client connections and also spawns new threads as a client connects, I can now switch to and from JFrames. I was reading about SwingWorkers and I've tried but couldn't seem to implement it using them :(

Comment: @ServletException If you're trying to use SwingWorker I would suggest creating a new question, and including the attempt you've made. It would help if you can reduce it down to just the servder or the client, and what you want to do with the swing worker. The swing worker is essentially a tool to do work on one thread, and publish the results to the EDT for updating the gui.

Comment: Thank you @matt, i got it working using SwingWorker now, I'm printing out the thread being used and everytime a client connects there's a new Thread being created for eg. SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-xx , I wanted to know if that's a problem, since a user can go back and forth between guis, it would amount to a high amount of Threads being created during the lifetime of the program.

Comment: i've read about thread pools and setting the max number of threads that can be made, but I don't think in my use case it would make sense, because it's now known how many times a user will switch back and forth between the Frames and creating a new thread for each time it happens

Comment: @ServletException it's hard to talk in the abstract when you have a specific example. You can create a new thread everytime a user clicks a button, that is not a lot of threads for a computer. Provided the resources are being managed properly. You shouldn't really be creating a bunch of JFrames though. In my example, I use an executor service which reuses the same thread.